# Obtain three level relationship on Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, orm, laravel-5, relationship

I'm trying to obtain a three level relationship data, but I'm lost about it using laravel 5.1

I'll try to explain my scenario, hope you can help me.

I've got two models called `Host` and `User`. 
This models are grouped by `Hostgroup` and `Usergroup` models, using a **Many To Many** relationship.

Then I've got a table called `usergroup_hostgroup_permissions` which relation an `Usergroup` with a `Hostgroup`:

```
+--------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type                 | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+--------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id           | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| usergroup_id | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| hostgroup_id | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| action       | enum('allow','deny') | NO   |     | allow               |                |
| enabled      | tinyint(1)           | NO   |     | 1                   |                |
+--------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

I'd like to obtain a list of users that belongs to an usergroup with a relation in this table with a hostgroup where my host belongs to.

For example:

My **host_1** belongs to `DEV_servers`. 
On `usergroup_hostgroup_permissions` table, there's an entry that allows `developers` to access to `DEV_servers`.
The usergroup `developer` has 3 users **user_1, user_2 and user_3**.

Any hint? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but it isn't quite clear, do you want to obtain the list using the host's id?

Comment: Hi @AhmadBaktashHayeri, I've only put one of the involved tables. I want to obtain users that has access to host_1. In order to obtain this we need wich hostgroups belongs to host_1, then obtain usergroups with 'allow' access to this hostgroups.

Comment: Hey Paco, did you check out my answer, I think it would serve your purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to obtain a list of *users* in a particular *host*, you need to ***nest*** all the underlying relationships (via `.`) using a `whereHas` method on the `User` model. i.e.

```
$users = User::whereHas('usergroup.hostgroups.hosts', function($q) use ($hostID){
    $q->where('id', $hostID);
})->get();
```

Moreover, if you want to check against whether the user is *allowed* to ***access*** that particular host, then you may chain another `where()` to the above as such:

```
$users = User::whereHas('usergroup.hostgroups.hosts', function($q) use ($hostID){
    $q->where('id', $hostID)->where('usergroup_hostgroup_permissions.action', 'allow');
})->get();
```

***Note:*** If you are warned on an ambiguous `id` field, try including the table `hosts` to which the id belongs to as well, i.e. `hosts.id`.

I am assuming that you have defined the relations for those models as follows:

```
class HostGroup extends Eloquent {

    /** ...
    */

    public function hosts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Host');
    }

    public function usergroups(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\UserGroup', 'usergroup_hostgroup_permissions');
    }
}
```

---

```
class Host extends Eloquent {
    /** ...
    */

    public function hostgroup() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\HostGroup');
    }
}
```

---

```
class UserGroup extends Eloquent {
    /** ...
    */    

    public function users(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }

    public function hostgroups(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\HostGroup', 'usergroup_hostgroup_permissions');
    }
}
```

---

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    /** ...
    */

    public function usergroup(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\UserGroup');
    }
}
```

Hope it turns out to be helpful.

Comment: Hi @ahmad-baktash-hayeri, your implementation works perfect... Thank you very much.