# Laravel Eloquent relationships with 3 Table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

Laravel 3 Table

table_user

- id
- name

table_barang

- id
- iduser
- name
- statusbarang_id

table_statusbarang

- id
- name

My code UserModels:

```
public function BarangModels()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(BarangModels::class, 'iduser');
    }
```

My code BarangModel :

```
public function UserModels()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(UserModels::class);
}

public function StatusBarangModels()
{
    return $this->hasOne(StatusBarangModels::class, 'idstatusbarang');
}
```

My Code StatusBarangModels :

```
public function BarangModels()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(BarangModels::class);
}
```

My Code Usercontroller

```
public function showdetail($id)
{
    $value = UserModels::find($id);
    return view('user/detailuser', compact('value'));
}
```

And, I want to select barangmodels (id, name) statusbarangmodels (name)
thank you

Comment: can you explain what you want to achieve? what do you mean select barangmodels?

Comment: Please clarify what you get in view and what expected to get, also you don't have any `idstatusbarang` column that you use in relations.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31775317/obtain-three-level-relationship-on-laravel-5

Comment: @James  sorry, barangmodels is wrong. table_barang is correct

Comment: if you want to just access these properties  (id, name), try $value->barangModels, you will get collection of these models, which you can go through with foreach for example.

Comment: @James Thanks you, James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add primary key of **BarangModel** as foreign key in **StatusBarangModels** for the relationship that you define in models. After adding key use the following code.

```
UserModels::with(['BarangModels'=>function($item){
    $item->with(['StatusBarangModels'=>function($query){
      $query->select('statusbarang_id','name');
      }])->select('id','name');
 }])->get();
```

You need to select foreign key in nested relationships so that eloquent can match primary and foreign key in tables.

This will work.
Thank you